# How to get the probability of P(Xi) = 1 / ( k + 1 ) when A[i] != x

Tags: algorithm

The question:

Now consider a deterministic linear search algorithm, which we refer to as
DETERMINISTIC-SEARCH. Specifically, the algorithm searches A for x in order,
considering A[1], A[2]; : : : ; A[n] until either it finds A[i] = x or it reaches the end of the array. Assume that all possible permutations of the input array are equally likely.

Suppose that there are k >= 1 indices i such that A[i] = x. What is the average-case running time of DETERMINISTIC-SEARCH?

I'm confused how to get the P(Xi) when A[i] is not equal to x. I know P(min(p1,..., pk) > i) = P(p1 > i) * ... * P(pk > i) = [(n-i) / n]^k = A, so why is P(Xi) not equal to A?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `n` different value in array `A`. So, there is `n!` different permutation for the values in `A`. Suppose `A[1] == x`, it means you you will find it by one comparison. Now, count the number of permutations that `x` is in the first place. It is `(n-1)!` that is for the other n-1 locations. Hence, the probability of `A[1] == x` is `(n-1)!/n! = 1/n`.

Now, try to compute the same things for the second place. It will be again `1/n` (as the same analysis for the first place is valid here). But you need two comparisons to find the `x`.

Therefore, the expected number of comparison is `\sum_{i=1}^n i*1/n =  1*1/n + 2*1/n + ... + n*1/n = (1+2+...+n)/n = (n+1)/2`.